# how to associate windows hosts file entry with process running on WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am running WSL2 (ubuntu) on Windows 10.
The WSL is running a process thats listening on a particular IP address - 192.168.3.1 (my apologies if I am not phrasing it correctly)

When I am in Windows browser, I want to type some name and have it resolved to the IP address inside WSL.

I have edited the Windows hosts file, and said something like:

```
192.168.3.1    alex
```

So now, in the browser, when I enter "alex" in the URL, I dont want it to search the internet -- I want it to get resolved to 192.168.3.1 inside WSL.

Thank you

Comment: Possibly a dumb question, but what does `ping alex` give as an IP?

Comment: so inside Widows, it correctly resolves to the correct IP address -- but I have just read that in WSL2, networking is virtualized.  So 192.168.3.1 inside WSL is not the same 192.168.3.1 as it it in Windows. At least thats how I understand it

Answer (score 2):

Try this on WSL2:

```
cd /etc <br>
sudo mv hosts hosts_bkp <br>
sudo ln -s /mnt/c/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts hosts
```

Now try to edit your `hosts` file by Windows.

Comment: If I `cat /etc/hosts`, the top of the file says `# This file was automatically generated by WSL...` which makes me think that creating a sym link isn't the solution.

Comment: @DharmaTurtle You skipped WSL documentation. You need to edit ```/etc/wsl.conf``` and add
```[network]
generateHosts = False``` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#network-settings